# Hide URL parameters ASPX / rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some long urls eg:
.../shop/stuk--amp-rosetter/rosetter.aspx?mode=1&nav=1910050@@SHOP5#.UNB4R2_8IQk

I would like to rewrite this to:
.../shop/stuk--amp-rosetter/rosetter

But still allow javascript to read/use the parameters after the . 
Is this possible?

Comment: Ideas: window.history.pushState() / replaceState() or .htaccess

Answer (score -1):

Well you could use ISAPI_Rewrite 3.